# Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient namespace missing Server class?

Tags: c#, .net, ssas

I've added a reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient to my C# project in hopes that I can automate some OLAP Cube processing.  All of the example code to instantiate a server connection looks something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

Server OLAPServer = new Server();
```

But if I use the above code, I receive the following error:

`Cannot resolve the symbol Server`

What is the issue?  Below is the reference that I've added.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Server` is in the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices` namespace, in `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll`

This DLL is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\%VERSION%\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll
```

Comment: Ahh well that makes sense.  Unfortunately, I can't find `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll` on my machine in that path. I'm looking on the server where Analysis Services is installed, and it must be outdated, because it's stuck on `%VERSION%` = 90

Comment: I only have 100 and 110 here, can't help for 90. Sorry :/

Comment: No problem.  You answered my question.  Now off to search for the right dll!  Thank you.

Comment: Hmm [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00b77a7c-5f58-4633-8528-7caf0a142234/check-for-existence-of-amomicrosoftanalysisservicesdll?forum=sqlanalysisservices) says it should be in the same place. `<SQL Server InstallationDrive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies`. Good luck with that.